# @angular/service-worker not working when offline and routing is configure

Tags: angular, service-worker, offline-caching

Is the first time I am working with service workers, I am following [this doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19S5ozevWighny788nI99worpcIMDnwWVmaJDGf_RoDY/edit#).

When it comes to the part of routing I don't manage to make it work properly. In case I specific http://localhost:4200/index.html it works, but with http://localhost:4200 I obtain the following:

[image: App not working when offline]

My ngsw-manifest.json once the build is done  looks like:

```
    {
  "routing": {
    "routes": {
      "/": {
        "prefix": false
      }
    },
    "index": "/index.html"
  },
  "static": {
    "urls": {
      ...
      "/favicon.ico": "84161b857f5c547e3699ddfbffc6d8d737542e01",
      "/index.html": "4791583ae04c8184ba443e8a1a57028d2b6a912e"
    },
    "_generatedFromWebpack": true
  }
}
```

And actually, I am using the @angular/service-worker:"^1.0.0-beta.16"

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns to be a stupid error, for those who suffer the same problem, on the chrome dev console > application just unregister the old service worker and refresh, now the routing should work properly.